# ERROR : yii CDbCriteria error when use SELECT AS

Tags: select, yii

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->alias = 'form';
    $criteria->select = "( to_char(form.created_at,'Mon') || '-' || extract(year from form.created_at) ) as monthyear";
    $criteria->group = "monthyear";
    $criteria->order = "monthyear DESC";

    $model = odkForm::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

why my **$model** return empty ? ...like this,, but not in other table

Any one can help ?

Comment: $models is **null** or in each model not exist property `monthyear`?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar yes, there is no monthyear,, but can we use `as` without set monthyear in model beacause i just call monthyear once, on the postgresql or other we can create `as` field every time without set model

Answer (score 0):

I think empty because in your model not exists property `monthyear`. So you can use `AS` **with name of fields which described in model**. Here a small example, I think this must work fine. Hope this help you.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->alias = 'form';
// because created_at exist in model
$criteria->select = "( to_char(form.created_at,'Mon') || '-' || extract(year from form.created_at) ) as created_at";
$criteria->group = "created_at";
$criteria->order = "created_at DESC";

$model = odkForm::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: Yes ...that's solve this problem but when we have to select all field and we create much dynamic field "as",, can that answer solve this problem ...thanks for everyone !